# Regex Sublime Text 3 SFTP Plugin Not Working

Tags: regex, sftp, sublimetext3

I have an odd error occurring when working with the SFTP plugin for Sublime Text 3. I have other folders mapped to remote directories successfully, but one of our branches is giving me some trouble.

It's known that we have some files in one particular subdirectory of our build directory that cause issues with the plugin due to their encoding, so I'm trying to exclude that folder altogether. This is the example structure:

```
/home/username/perforce/build_current/
/home/username/perforce/build_current/dir1
/home/username/perforce/build_current/dir2
/home/username/perforce/build_current/dir3 <-- the problem directory
/home/username/perforce/build_current/dir4
```

with some arbitratry number of files and subdirectories in each dir-n. I've added the following `ignore_regexes` to my `sftp-config.json` file:

```
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini",
    "\\.swp", "\\.rej", "\\.dat", "\\.gif", "\\.png", "\\.tif",
    "/dir3/"
]
```

When I attempt to download the remote directory to my local file system using the plugin via right-click --> SFTP/FTP --> Download Folder I get the following error:

```
Listing remote folder "/home/username/perforce/build_current/dir3/Content/Resources/" ... failure (Encoding error)
```

I understand *why* the error was thrown (it's trying to decode something that isn't utf-8) but what I don't get is *why* the ignore_regex wasn't applied in this case to avert the scenario that could cause the error (i.e. recursing into dir3). Does anyone have experience with using this plugin that could provide some guidance?

Thanks!